# Will there be efficiency issue if access to keyChain frequently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I have a `tableView` that row height needs to adjust dynamically according to the value stored in `keyChain`, so comes the problem.

Just wondering how to verify it quantitatly.

Comment: Why dont you just fetch all of them to memory (eg.Array) to work with instead of access them one by one multiple times?

Comment: Yes loading all the values at once (in-memory) and using that value will definitely  improve the performance. To test the performance you can use `XCTest​Case`'s `measure` block

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Thanks, i will learn about the XCTestCase and have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to load all values `ONCE`, ie., store in memory.